# why i get this? , line 17 subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"]) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python3


import subprocess
import optparse


def get_arguments():
        parser = optparse.OptionParser()
        parser.add_option("-i", "--interface", dest="interface", help="goo")
        parser.add_option("-m", "--mac", dest="new_mac", help="yeees")
        return parser.parse_args()

def change_mac (interface, new_mac):
        print ("changing MAC ADDRESS FOR :{} to {}" (interface, new_mac)
        subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"])     ## the problem
        subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "hw ", " ether ", new_mac])
        subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "up"])

get_arguments()
change_mac (options.interface, options.new_mac)
```

[image: error]

Comment: Please properly format your code. The call to `print` in the line above it lacks a closing `)` -- this is just a typo.

Comment: It should be `print("changing MAC ADDRESS FOR :{} to {}".format(interface, new_mac))` (missing closing paren, and missing call to `.format`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error is declared at line 17 but actually occurs at the end of line 16. You just need to close the parenthesis of the call of the function `print`. Also, the way you try to add the variables `interface` and `new_mac` in the string is incorrect; you need to use the `format` function.

Here is the code fixed:

```
[...]
def change_mac (interface, new_mac):
        print ("changing MAC ADDRESS FOR :{} to {}".format(interface, new_mac)) # FIXED
        subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"])
[...]
```